# Expected number of steps needed until every point is visited in bounded simple symmetric random walk?

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

I was wondering how to calculate this. Say the state-space is $\{1, \dots, N \}$. Would it be correct to calculate the expected value of the first hitting time of $N$ starting from $1$ by using the coupon's collector formula?

Comment: In coupon collecting you never go backwards, unlike random walk.

Comment: @saulspatz  ok, is there any way I can tackle this expected value without setting up $N$ equations with $N$ unknowns?

Comment: Yes, you you can set up a second-order linear recurrence relation (difference equation.)  Are you familiar with those?

Comment: @saulspatz yes I did that and I found $\psi_1=\psi_i + i-1$ if we call $\psi_i$ the expected value starting from $i$. By the way, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by not going backwards in coupon collecting. If that's the case, how come we could apply the formula to find the number of throws of a die until every side has appeared at least once?

Comment: In coupon collecting the state is the number of distinct coupons you've collected so far; that never goes down.  In random walk, you can go to the left or right.  Also in coupon collecting, the transition probabilities are different in different states, whereas in random walk, they're the same, except at the barriers.

Comment: @saulspatz I see but what I mean is that it could technically be applied just for the journey starting from state $1$ to state $N$ right? Because every step to the right is to a new never visited before site while every step to the left is to an already visited site. Or is that still wrong?

Comment: I'll write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $e_k$ be the expected number of steps to reach state $N$ if we are currently in state $k$.  Then $$e_k = 1+\frac12(e_{k-1}+e_{k+1})\tag1$$
because we take one step and then with probability $\frac12$ we need $e_{k-1}$ more steps on average, and with probability $\frac12$ we need $e_{k+1}$ more steps on average.  We have the boundary condition $e_N=0$.

We can rewrite $(1)$ as $$e_{k+1}-2e_k+e_{k-1}=-2$$ which has characteristic equation $$r^2-2r+1=0$$ which has $1$ as a double root.  Therefore, the general solution to the homogeneous equation is $e_k=a$ for a constant $a$.

Now we must find a particular solution to $(1)$.  From the form of the equation,, we guess that a quadratic polynomial will work, and we quickly find that $e_k=-k^2$ is a solution.  The general solution to $(1)$ is the general solution to the associated homogeneous equation, plus any particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation, so the general solution is $$e_k=a-k^2$$  Substituting the boundary condition, we find $a=N^2$ so that $e_k=K^2-k^2$ and the expected number of steps starting in state $1$ is $$e_1=\boxed{N^2-1}$$

Observe that this is nothing like the answer for the coupon collector's problem.  The two problems have nothing in common except that the absorbing state is state $N$.